# CloudFormation powershell to run as domain admin + elevated priviledge

Tags: active-directory, powershell, amazon-cloudformation

So... I'm writing some cloud formation templates.

Using cfn-init, I get the machine to join the domain, and now I need to run in a Domain Admin context as local admin with elevated privilege to:

- Add a domain service account with log on as a service right
- Set that account as SQL server service account
- Set appropriate disk permission

However it seems cfn-init powershell are executed as System account, and that it can't spawn other PowerShell process or something?

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We're heading down a similar path ourselves. I have not tested this answer yet, but according to the following page PowerShell via cfn-init cannot do what you're asking... but the SysInternals PsExec.exe utility can:
[Installing a Windows role as another user](http://www.cepheid.org/~jeff/?p=60)
Hope this helps,
Ant.